# ListView comes to first position again after scrolling

Tags: android

Hi all I have listview in my application but after scrolling to bottom it again sets to first position.

```
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    start = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
    listView.setSelectionFromTop(start, 0);
```

after removing following code it works fine but after scrolling setOnItemClickListener does not work.

```
listView.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
            if ( scrollState == OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE )
            {
              listView.invalidateViews();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {}




    });
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: where are you setting the `onItemClickListener`

Comment: I had tried it in onCreate and in onResume also

Comment: set the `onItemClickListener` on `getView` of the adapter method

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
listView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
   @Override
   public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
   }

   @Override
   public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
       int lastInScreen = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;
       if((lastInScreen == totalItemCount)){
          new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
              @Override
              public void run() {
                    listView.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
              }
           },1000); // change (1000) value as per your requirement like : when list shown last item then after 1 second list scrolled to 0 position
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Haresh where to add this method? After adding it in listView.setOnScrollListener it gives me error as - The method onScrollChanged(int, int, int, int) of type new AbsListView.OnScrollListener(){} must override or implement a supertype method

Comment: Now listView does not get scrolled.